# Summernote JS : ordered list

Tags: javascript, html, summernote

I'd like the ordered list function to be 'continuous' if I add text between two points.

Example :

Step 1 : Creation of a ordered list with two elements : OK

[image: Step1]

Step 2 : I add text between this two points by making two line breaks at the end of 1. NOT OK

[image: Step 2]

But I'd like "2. Title 2" to stay (like in Word for instance).

Would you have an idea? Thank you

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I think your only option is to do manual numbering (eg. 1), 2), 3))